# Comparar dos arreglos multidimensionales con array_udiff

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente porción de código para comprar dos arreglos:

```
$a = array(
         array('cuenta' => 1000), 
         array('cuenta' => 2000)
        );

$b = array(
        array('cuenta' => 1000),
        array('cuenta' => 2000),
        array('cuenta' => 3000)
    );

print_r($a);
print_r($b);

$d = array_udiff($a, $b, function($x, $y) use ($a, $b){
    if($x['cuenta'] == $y['cuenta']){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
});

print_r($d);
```

Cuando ejecutó lo anterior me muestra en la pantalla

```
// Arreglo $a
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 2000
        )

)

// Arreglo $b
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 2000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 3000
        )

)

// Arreglo $d
Array
(
)
```

Que debo corregir en mi código o qué debo hacer para que cuando ejecuté dicho código el resultado del arreglo `$d` sea este:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cuenta] => 3000
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le hice dos correcciones a tu código. 1) le inverti los nombres de tus array, debido a que el segundo esta mas completo. 2) en la condición de diferente retorno el valor -1

```
$b = array(
     array('cuenta' => 1000), 
     array('cuenta' => 2000)
    );

$a = array(
    array('cuenta' => 1000),
    array('cuenta' => 2000),
    array('cuenta' => 3000)
);

print_r($a);
print_r($b);

$d = array_udiff($a, $b, function($x, $y) use ($a, $b){
if($x['cuenta'] == $y['cuenta']){
    return 0;
}else{
    return -1;
}
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($d);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono a la perfección